# MySQL ordering by a nextid column

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm trying to pull some info out of a [Moodle](http://moodle.org) database.
There is one part that has a list of questions that you can order in whatever way you want through the Moodle interface.
However, the way it stores this in the database is making it hard for me to make a custom query that orders these items in the same manner outside of the moodle interface.

So there is a column ID, then a column NEXTPAGEID.

Here are the first 5 rows in the SQL to give you an example of what I need:

ID: 1; NEXTPAGEID: 3
ID: 3; NEXTPAGEID: 118
ID: 9; NEXTPAGEID: 10
ID: 10; NEXTPAGEID: 515
ID: 11; NEXTPAGEID: 12

So the order I really need is ID: 1, 3, 118, (whatever the NEXTPAGEID of 118 is), etc.

So is this possible in SQL or do I have to deal with it in the PHP when I output this query?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  You'll have to do it in PHP.

Comment: Any tips on the direction to go in for the PHP?

Comment: Just loop through it and build an array.